# App to keep track of the amount of objects on surfaces in a house

Tags: android, web-apps

### Task

The task is to keep a periodic overview of the objects, and amount of objects, per surface area in a house. A periodic check is performed where people take a picture of a surface, then list the objects on the surface.

When they select a surface, they will see how many objects were on the surface last check, (and optionally the photos of last checks, and optionally a list of objects of last check.)

### Requirements

1. The app shall allow users to first select a room, then select a surface in the room.
2. The app shall allow users to toggle between seeing past pictures or not.
3. The app shall allow users to toggle between seeing the list of past objects
4. The app is open source.
5. The app is Android compatible.

### Ideal Requirements

1. The app has built in object recognition that automatically detects objects if they are detected with a tunable amount of minimum certainty/confidence.
2. The app is able to ask the user to provide a "label" for an object that is segmented, but not identified clearly, by showing the object and segmentation and asking the user to name the object. (Also the user could improve (certain parts of) the segmentation)
3. The app allows users to "quickly" zoom in and "circle/free select/segment" the object, which allows the app to learn based on new samples.
4. The app allows asking the user to select detecting objects in a certain order (e.g. left to right, or bottom right to top left etc.), and allows the lists of objects, when shown, to be shown either in that order in which the user listed the objects in the past check, or in alphabetical order.
5. The app is able to provide insights in the trends of the amounts of objects on a surface over time e.g. using a graph.
6. if cloud based training is enabled, users are able to select which images, segmentations and labels are shared using a swipe left or swipe right interface.

### Existing Apps

1. Carnet appears to be able to take pictures and store them but it does not provide the hierarchical structure.
2. Infinilist appears to facilitate the hierarchical lists but does appear to provide the photo integration.

### Question

Is there an app that suits these requirements and what would you recommend as starting point(s) to combine these functionalities into a (pre-existing) app?